# Haskell map but remove items that don't follow condition

Tags: dictionary, haskell, functional-programming

The function should take a list of tuples, and return the ones that have sum > 5

Let's say I have the following code:

```
fn :: [(Int, Int)] -> [(Int, Int)]

fn tuples = map (\(x,y) -> if (x + y) > 5 then (x,y) else (0,0)) tuples
```

`fn [(3,4), (4,4), (0,1)]` returns `[(3,4),(4,4),(0,0)]` but really I just want it to return `[(3,4),(4,4)]`

Is this possible in haskell while still following the type signature?

Comment: Well, the input type wouldn't change. Would the output type change if it returned your desired output instead?

Comment: I dont see a concept of "empty tuple" in haskell

Comment: You can't add or remove elements with `map`, only transform them. Have you tried `filter`?

Comment: "I dont see a concept of "empty tuple" in haskell" You don't need an "empty tuple". You have `[(3,4),(4,4),(0,0)]` (a list containing three tuples), and you want `[(3,4),(4,4)]` (a list containing two tuples). Both of these are type `[(Int, Int)]` (a list of tuples).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you're asking for is [mapMaybe](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Maybe.html#v:mapMaybe):

> ```
> mapMaybe :: (a -> Maybe b) -> [a] -> [b]
> ```
>
> base Data.Maybe
>
> The `mapMaybe` function is a version of `map` which can throw out elements. In particular, the functional argument returns something of type `Maybe b`. If this is `Nothing`, no element is added on to the result list. If it is `Just b`, then b is included in the result list.

The smallest change to use it in your code would be:

```
import Data.Maybe

fn :: [(Int, Int)] -> [(Int, Int)]
fn tuples = mapMaybe (\(x,y) -> if (x + y) > 5 then Just (x,y) else Nothing) tuples
```

However, in this specific case, you don't actually transform, you just remove. If you don't plan on adding transformation later, `filter` is more suitable:

```
fn = filter (\(x,y) -> x+y > 5)
```

Answer (score 4):

Bit of a weird question, but after the comment

> I dont see a concept of “empty tuple” in haskell

I guess I see where you're coming from. Actually Haskell does have “empty tuples”: the unit type `()` is the type of “tuples with zero elements”. So what you're thinking of seems to be

```
fn tuples = map (\(x,y) -> if x + y > 5 then (x,y) else ()) tuples
```

But that doesn't work because `()` is *a different type* from `(Int,Int)`. The elements of a list must all have the same type. Even if it did work, à la dynamic-types, the result of `fn [(3,4), (4,4), (0,1)]` would then actually be `[(3,4), (4,4), ()]`. I.e. you'd still get three elements, just one of them would be “boring”.

`map` does in fact by design guarantee to never change the number of elements in the list, only the values of their elements. So if that's what you *want*, you need to use a different function. The closest to your approach would be [`concatMap`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:concatMap):

```
fn tuples = concatMap (\(x,y) -> if x + y > 5 then [(x,y)] else []) tuples
```

What happens here can also be described in two steps:

- You map a function that generates a list for each element. The result is thus a list of lists.
- You flatten that list.

So `[(3,4), (4,4), (0,1)]` -> `[[(3,4)], [(4,4)], []]` -> `[(3,4), (4,4)]`.

Really though, there's no need to use a mapping step at all here – the elements are kept as they are eventually, so [`filter`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:filter) is the tool to use.